# SO for video editors?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren’t programming questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)

I think a video editor website to the tune of the SO family would be awesome.

Comment: Make​​​​​​​​​​​​​ one.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start a [StackExchange Site](http://stackexchange.com) for it.

StackExchange is basically the engine that StackOverflow, Meta, SuperUser and Serverfault all run on, but is able to be customized to whatever topic you like.

Comment: I dont want to pay, I know web coding, but if these guys do it then everyone gains. If I do it, it will just be a hassle.

Comment: Currently the Trilogy (SO, SU, and SF) are very much programming related, with SU being how to use programs, SO how to write them, and SF how to manage the platforms they are on. Video Editing either goes towards the tune of SU, or something that doesn't fit in that trilogy.

Comment: It is kinda of sad to say, but this is almost a 'Canned Answer' to these sorts of questions. Unless there is something that really fits into the trilogy, the best option is to make your own site.